# Following programming styles -- update poor adherence?

Tags: coding-style

I have a project I am working on that is written in Python. The variable/class/function/everything names do not adhere to the Python style guide.

example: a variable might be called `myRandomVariable` instead of the proper: `my_random_variable`

My question is, is it worth combing through all the code (around 10,000 lines) to fix all the naming convention problems or should I just say, 'the heck with it -- it works'?

Thanks

Edited to give example

Comment: These conventions are to bring a sense of order in your code.If your team has no problem with that,it is fine

Comment: It is good to see that you paused to think about it. If possible comb through code only to see/fix any inconsistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because there is a Python style guide, it does not mean that all Python code should adhere to it. The most important thing to consider in a code base is that it's consistent with itself, at LEAST on a per-file basis, preferably across the project!

Comment: 100% agree! It doesn't matter which convention you choose, provided you choose one and everybody sticks to it.

Comment: This is true for all the languages (at least all the languages i have coded in)!

Comment: My biggest irk is not so much the lack of adherence to the Python guide, but the every-now-and-then lack of adherence to its *own* style. It kind of bugs me that there are some names that don't fit the project's own style. I think I will follow the general consensus that, so long as the project is consistent with itself, all is well. Thanks.

Comment: Now that's a perfectly good reason to be irked! If it's generally consistent within each file I'd leave it, if it's a mix then my policy would be to fix it a file at a time, doing each one when the need to edit the file arises.

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for your second option. They are just styles. Everyone will have their own style. You don't need to be in compilance with defined styles to say your product is great.